# How to determine the type of a passed vector to a template function

Tags: c++, templates

Hi guys maybe you can help me out on this,

I've two vectors (vecInt, vecDouble). Obviously one is of sort int and the other is of sort double.

But how do I check the types of those vectors in the if and the else if?

```
    if (TYPE OF VECTOR == INT) {
        std::cout << "vecInt: ";
    }
    else if (TYPE OF VECTOR == DOUBLE) {
        std::cout << "vecDouble: ";
    }
```

Comment: The whole point of templates is to avoid having to know the type. Could you not print the vector type *before* calling the template function while you still know the type?

Comment: That's true. I'm doing this right now and now I realized hat the template function is definitely not the right place to do so. I will edit my question to a more general approach.

Comment: Your edit doesn't change the question, it just makes my answer look like I make stuff up out of thin air.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But how do I check the types of those vectors in the if and the else if?

You don't. That is not to say you can't, only that you shouldn't. This sort of branching is not going to give you the solution you want, 9 out of 10 times. A superior choice is overloading. Instead of adding a branch, add a call to a helper function, one that you then overload to get the behaviors you want.

It would look like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void output_helper(std::vector<T>*) {}

void output_helper(std::vector<int>*) {
    std::cout << "vecInt: ";
}

void output_helper(std::vector<double>*) {
    std::cout << "vecDouble: ";
}

template <typename T>
void output(std::vector<T>* vO) {
    output_helper(vO);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < vO->size(); i++) {
        std::cout << (*vO).at(i) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
    output(&v);
    return 0;
}
```

Which indeed outputs

```
vecInt: 1 2 3
```

As you can see [live](https://ideone.com/tXr9HK). A major bonus to overloading is that you can extend the behavior of `output` without modifying it. Simply add an overload for another vector type.

And by the way, consider ditching the pass by pointer, and pass by reference, as one would in idiomatic C++.

Comment: Thank you for your solution!!! Please don't be mad on me for editing my question. Why is it a "bad" to do stuff like this in templates?

Comment: @Kai - I'm not mad, I'm just foreseeing the slew of comments that ask me where I conjured that advice about pointers from. Anyway.. I didn't say it's bad. Only that it's probably not what you want. Customizing templates on **specific** types is is not robust when done in a chain of branches. An overload set is easily extendable, and there's no branching to be seen. The compiled functions "just does what it's supposed to" without any checks.

Comment: I probably would have used template specialization for `output_helper` and just passed it `T` instead of the actual `vector` pointer. Also using `at()` in the `for` loop is wasted overhead since the loop is already doing its own range checking. Use `operator[]` instead, or better iterators, or even a [range-for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Answer (score 3):

You can use type traits in C++11 and C++14:

```
#include <type_traits>

if (std::is_same<T, int>::value) {
    std::cout << "vecInt: ";
}
else if (std::is_same<T, double>::value) {
    std::cout << "vecDouble: ";
}
```

Note that this is a runtime check, but the compiler should be able to optimize it away.

In C++17, you can instead use `if constexpr`, which makes this a guaranteed compile-time check with no runtime overhead, and you can also use the `_v` version of `is_same` in order to not have to write `::value` every time:

```
if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>) {
    std::cout << "vecInt: ";
}
else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>) {
    std::cout << "vecDouble: ";
}
```

In practice, however, even the former version should end up with no runtime check, as the compiler will optimize away the branches, as the if clauses are compile-time constant expressions. In each template specialization, the compiler can see that one of the branches can never be taken, and will therefore delete the branch.

Comment: "Note that this is a runtime check." → Typically, it will be optimized.

Comment: @Constructor Yeah, though it's not guaranteed. I didn't check it.

Comment: I mean that in fact the difference between `if` and `if constexpr` in such situation is not the difference between compile-time and run-time checking of the condition. Simple `if` requires both branches to be compiled successfully despite the condition. `if constexpr` doesn't have such requirement so this feature is very useful while writing the templated code.